# Orthogonal matrix of operators (and the quantum rigid rotor)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, rigid-body-dynamics

While reading the section on the rigid rotor in Weinberg's *Lectures on Quantum Mechanics* I have found a problem when dealing with a matrix of operators. First of all, clasically, to describe a rigid rotor we introduce a time dependent rotation matrix $R(t) \in SO(3)$ so that the position of any of the particles (labelled by $n$) is given by:

$$ x_{n,i}(t) = \sum_{a}R_{ia}(t) x_{n,a}^0 $$

where $x_{n,a}^0$ are the positions of the particles in a reference frame which is rotating with the body. A key step when deriving the rotational energy in this classical setup is to realize that the orthogonality of the matrix implies, taking a time derivative:

$$ \dot{R}^T R + R^T \dot{R} = 0 \,\,\Rightarrow\,\, \dot{R}^T R = -R^T \dot{R} = -\left(\dot{R}^T R\right)^T $$

So $\dot{R}^T R$ is antisymmetric and therefore we can parametrize it with 3 real parameters as follows:

$$ \left(\dot{R}^T R\right)_{ab} = \sum_{i} \dot{R}_{ia} R_{ib} = \sum_c \epsilon_{abc}\Omega_c $$

This is important because we can express the rotational Hamiltonian in terms of the parameters $\Omega_c$ (which are something like *angular velocities*, at least that's the interpretation for a rotation around a fixed axis), and in this process the moment of inertia tensor appears naturally. Now, let's go to the quantum case, which is the interesting one. The dynamical variables are the components of the rotation matrix $R_{ia}(t)$, so we introduce a set of Hermitian operators $\hat{R}_{ia}(t)$ whose eigenvalues are the components $R_{ia}$ of specific rotations. These operators commute with one another (like the different components of the position operator commute) but they do not commute in principle with their time derivatives (which are somehow related to the canonical conjugate momenta). Now, we still have an orthogonality condition for this *matrix of operators* which implies:

$$ \left( \hat{R}^T \hat{R} \right)_{ab} = \sum_i \hat{R}_{ia} \hat{R}_{ib} = \delta_{ab} \,\, \Rightarrow \,\, \left( \dot{\hat{R}}^T \hat{R} \right)_{ab} = \sum_i \dot{\hat{R}}_{ia} \hat{R}_{ib} = - \sum_i \hat{R}_{ia} \dot{\hat{R}}_{ib} = - \left(\hat{R}^T \dot{\hat{R}}\right)_{ab} $$

The problem is that now, since the operators and their derivatives do not commute, we cannot prove that $\dot{\hat{R}}^T \hat{R}$ is antisymmetric as a matrix of operators (which would be necessary to introduce the three parameters as before). This is a consequence of the fact that $(\hat{A}\hat{B})^T \neq \hat{B}^T \hat{A}^T$ if the operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ do not commute. Explicitly, we have:

$$ \left(\dot{\hat{R}}^T \hat{R}\right)_{ab} = - \sum_i \hat{R}_{ia} \dot{\hat{R}}_{ib} = -\sum_i \left[\hat{R}_{ia}, \dot{\hat{R}}_{ib}\right] - \sum_i \dot{\hat{R}}_{ib} \hat{R}_{ia} = \\ = -\sum_i \left[\hat{R}_{ia}, \dot{\hat{R}}_{ib}\right] - \left(\left(\dot{\hat{R}}^T \hat{R}\right)^T\right)_{ab} $$

I am really struggling with this problem (I even tried to express a general $SO(3)$ matrix of operators as the exponential of a general antisymmetric matrix of operators, but even with that I do not know how to introduce the three parameters that play the role of angular velocities), and I think part of the problem might come from the fact that the orthogonality conditions provide hidden relations between the operators $\hat{R}_{ia}(t)$, so that we are in some sense dealing with a constrained system (a topic in which I am completely lost). Anyway, this is only a guess and any kind of help would be really appreciated!